# Sending email alert

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

After migrating data to Azure Sql database need to send email alert which I did not find in azure data factory

In azure logicapps unable to see Azure sql database connector like below image
[image]

Comment: In ADF it's not possible to send email alert but you can achieve this through Azure logicapps

Comment: You’re all over the place. Explain exactly what you’re doing. You’ve mentioned ADF, LogicApps and sending an email. What’s the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
After migrating data to Azure Sql database need to send email alert which I did not find in azure data factory
```

AFAIK sending email alert is not possible through azure data factory, but you can achieve this using Azure logic Apps by following this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-send-email)

In logic App Create When a http request is received trigger by taking  your adf Json schema as shown below.
[image]

Then In Outlook 365 connector you can choose send email action and you can retrieve your adf details like data factory name, pipeline name and message.
[image]

Then the email gets triggered  and the recipient get email alert .
[image]
[image]